# Saving in Form ODBC Timeout

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I've got a remote linked table I'm dealing with: `tblOrderNotes`. I can open the table and manually edit the values in the rows no problem.

When a user opens a form to edit a row of this table the ODBC connection times out every time. It also locks the table such that I can no longer manually edit anything unless I re-link the tables.

I'm fairly unfamiliar with access, is there any good way to debug this problem?

[image: Form Snapshot]

[image: NoteText Snapshot]

Comment: "When a user opens a form to edit a row of this table the ODBC connection times out every time." - Does that happen on the same computer and user logon you use to edit the table? Depending on the ODBC connection type used it can be computer or user profile dependent.

Comment: It happens on more than one machine, and I've tried a couple different SQL auths in the connection string. Specifically the restriced database account we normally use as well as sa. They all act the same way - timeout and lockout in form, work fine in the table

Comment: If in the exact same environment that you can edit the table the form has issues than it is not really an ODBC connectivity issue but something wrong with the way the form is trying to write data. Try to change the Recordset Type to Dynaset (Inconsistent Updates). That will help if the "table" is not actually a table but a View in the back end. If that does not work then you will need a lot more information than what you have posted for a meaningful answer.